# Разнородные ошибки при работе с динамической памятью

Tags: c, динамические-массивы

У меня есть три функции, в которых XCode иногда (не каждый запуск) видит разные ошибки. Когда выполнение прерывается, ошибки всегда одинаковые, в одинаковых местах. Привожу функцию main:

```
    int main(){
        for (int size = MIN_SIZE; size<= MAX_SIZE; size+=SIZE_STEP){
            double * Array = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double));
            Array = ArrayGenerate(size);
            struct returnvalue input = Clock(Array, size);
            const int count = *(input.countReturn);
            long ** TimeTableInput = (long**)malloc((count)*sizeof(long*));
                for (int i=0; i<count; ++i)
                    TimeTableInput[i] = (long*)malloc(REPEAT_COUNT*sizeof(long));
            long sum[count], result[count];
            int i;
            for (i=0; i<count; i++){
    
             for (int j=0; j<REPEAT_COUNT; j++){
                        sum[i] += (TimeTableInput+i*j);
    
            }

  В строке с объявлением TimeTableInput возникает ошибка Incorrect checksum for freed object 0x1006115d8: probably modified after being freed.

    struct returnvalue  Clock (double * Array, int size){
    void *ext_library;
    const  int* const count = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    sort_info_t * sort;
    sort = (sort_info_t*)malloc(sizeof(sort_info_t));
    sort_info_t * (*GetList)(int* count);


    ext_library = dlopen("/Users/glebsokolov/Sr.so",RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!ext_library)
        fprintf(stderr,"dlopen() error: %s\n", dlerror());
    GetList = dlsym(ext_library,"GetSortList");
        long **  TimeTable = (long**)malloc((*count)*sizeof(long*));
        for (int i=0; i<*count; ++i)
        TimeTable[i] = (long*)malloc(REPEAT_COUNT*sizeof(long));
    sort = GetList (count);
    sort_info_t sort_descriptor;
    sort_func_t  Variations;
    for (int i=0; i<*count; i++){
        sort_descriptor = *(sort+i);
        for (int k=0; k<REPEAT_COUNT; k++){
                Variations = sort_descriptor.sort;
                struct timespec time1;
                struct timespec time2;
                clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID , &time1);
                Variations(&Array[k],size);
                clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID , &time2);
                long t1 = time1.tv_nsec, t2 = time2.tv_nsec;
                *(TimeTable+i*k) = MAX(t1,t2)- MIN(t1,t2);
        }
}
    struct returnvalue  result = {
        TimeTable[*count],
        count
    };
        dlclose(ext_library);
        free (sort);
        return result;
    
}

Далее, в этой функции та же ошибка возникает в строке с инициализацией ext_library.

    double * ArrayGenerate (int size)
    {
    double ** Array;
    Array = (double**)malloc(REPEAT_COUNT*sizeof(double*));
    for (int i=0; i<REPEAT_COUNT; i++){
        Array[i] = (double*)malloc(MAX_SIZE * sizeof(double));
        RandomArray(Array[i], size);
    }
        return *Array;
    }

В этой функции в строчке с маллоком тоже возникает та же ошибка. Я так понимаю, дело в чём-то очень простом, но я не вижу в чём.
```

Comment: Я уже после публикации заметил, что ошибки вообще-то одинаковые :)

Comment: Я так же посмотрел что делает маллок. Пишет: Attempting excessively large memory allocation:  18446744062256305488 bytes
GuardMalloc[executivefile-10163]: If you really wanted to allocate so much memory, launch your executable with the environment variable MALLOC_PERMIT_INSANE_REQUESTS set to any value to circumvent this check.

Comment: `18446744062256305488` это -1. Смотрите на `count`

Comment: Действительно, count нигде не инициализировалась...Поправил. Но теперь возникает ошибка в строке  Variations(&Array[k],size); (Bad Access code = 1) В чём там дело?

Comment: Покажите **весь** код. Не вижу объявление структуры `returnvalue`,`MAX_SIZE`,`MIN_SIZE`.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Raezqiy0

Comment: Мало показали. Единственное пока увидел вы постоянно путаете числа с указателями. 
`*(TimeTable+i*k) = MAX(t1,t2)- MIN(t1,t2);`, `sum[i] += (TimeTableInput+i*j);` . `assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast` Исправьте все предупреждения компилятора сначала.